# Silverlight ListBoxDragDropTarget Errors in Dynamically Added Lists

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, toolkit

I am using the Silverlight Toolkit **ListBoxDragDropTarget** and running into errors using it with dynamically added lists. I am dynamically adding user controls containing lists to a layout Grid.  When I drag an item from one list to another in the Grid, I get the following Exception.

> throw new Error("Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight 2 Application Value does
>   not fall within the expected range.
>   at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr
>   ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)\n
>   at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr
>   objectPtr, String methodName, Object[]
>   rawData)\n   at
>   MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_Insert[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1
>   collection, Int32 index, Object
>   value)\n   at
>   System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.InsertImpl(Int32
>   index, Object value)\n   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.InsertImpl(Int32
>   index, Object value)\n   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.InsertInternal(Int32
>   index, Object value)\n   at
>   System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Insert(Int32
>   index, T value)\n   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControlExtensions.InsertItem(ItemsControl
>   that, Int32 index, Object item)\n
>   ....

Answer (score 0):

I can't pin point the exact answer, but **Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application Value does not fall within the expected range** is going to be a reference (probably binding) to an item that does not exist.

If the lists are dynamic perhaps the Visual Tree does not have a reference to the item you are dragging? You might get over this using an MVVM pattern, and binidng your lists to ObservableCollection properties in your VM.

Can you post a more complete code repro?